# Sprite Kit - jerky animation

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios7, sprite-kit

I have this code

```
  // load animation
  NSMutableArray *images=[NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:14];
  for (int i=1; i<=14; i++) {
    NSString *fileName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"fish%d.png",i];
    SKTexture *tempTexture=[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:fileName];
    [images addObject:tempTexture];
  }

  NSUInteger numberOfFrames = [images count];

  [SKTexture preloadTextures:images withCompletionHandler:^(void){
    SKAction *nadar = [SKAction animateWithTextures:images timePerFrame:1.0f/numberOfFrames];
    SKAction *forever = [SKAction repeatActionForever:nadar];
    [self.fish runAction:forever];
  }];
```

I have this jerky animation

[image]

I don't know if it is clear watching the video, but the fish scales vertically and horizontally for one frame (you can see a red halo below the fish when that happens).

I reduced the speed for the simulator, so you can see the problem. The fish is resizing, moving position, etc., on the animation below, but it was supposed to be steady because it has no animation beyond keyframe animation.

[image]

All the images have the same size and the animation is perfect and smooth, as you can see it running on Photoshop on the next gif.

[image]

Any idea of what may be causing this?

Comment: Does all your images (frames) have the same size?

Comment: yes, I said that before the last image... :)

Comment: Sorry, I misread that and though that you had exported a GIF from Photoshop

Comment: the animation is perfect, as you can see by the last picture but spritekit is squishing, moving, resizing the fish in all directions. Very weird

Comment: Does your texture atlas honour the extra transparent pixels around the frames?

Comment: You could give a shoot to animateWithTextures:timePerFrame:resize:restore:
Try setting resize to YES/NO see if anything helps.

Comment: I had the same issue with using `SKTextureAtlas`. Try again without `preloadTextures:withCompletionHandler:`

Comment: Try packing the atlas with TexturePacker (trial version suffices) just to see whether this effect may be due to a bug in Apple's textureatlas tool. I've certainly seen this effect before and I believe it's reported as an issue. I believe it has something to do with rotated frames, so if you use TexturePacker try unchecking the frame rotation checkbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [animateWithTextures:timePerFrame:resize:restore:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKAction/animateWithTextures%3atimePerFrame%3aresize%3arestore%3a) setting resize to YES.

Comment: Yes, that solved the problem but the problem still happens in the first run of the animation, as the animation loops the problem vanishes. A strange thing here is this RESIZE to YES. In theory the problem is caused by SpriteKit resizing the images but if I put RESIZE to NO, the problem persists.

Comment: Just a thought, haven't investigated this, but is it possible that it has to do with the `anchorPoint` which defaults to center? Maybe when it is swapping frames it readjusts relationship to `anchorPoint` based on non-transparent pixels and not the actual image dimensions ?  Just a theory. If you are ok with posting the frames, I'd be interested in testing that theory.

Answer (score 0):

After finding this thread, it solved parts of my problem. The other is when the textures first animated, there was still some jerkiness. Since I'm using `SKTextureAtlas`, my problem was using the wrong function to preload the texture.

Cause:

```
[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:textureName]
```

Resolved by using:

```
[atlas textureNamed:textureName]
```

**Example**

```
SKTextureAtlas *atlas = [SKTextureAtlas atlasNamed:@"walk"];
NSMutableArray *textures = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSString *textureName in atlas.textureNames)
     [textures addObject:[atlas textureNamed:textureName]];
```

Please refer to apple documentation for using `SKTextureAtlas`: [Working With Sprites](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Sprites/Sprites.html)

Hope this helps someone else with the same problem.